# Cannot install numpy for PyPy 3.8 on Win10

Tags: numpy, windows-10, pypy

I am attempting to try out pypy, and I can install a few packages, but the important ones like Numpy and Pandas go boom!!!  I get similar issues if I try it within PyCharm.

see below.  Also at some point I also saw this error.

````
     Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
      Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
      A better performance should be easily gained by switching
      Blas library.

  Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
```

```
pypy -m pip install --extra-index-url https://antocuni.github.io/pypy-wheels/manylinux2010 numpy

```
C:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\pypy\pypy3.8-v7.3.7-win64>pypy -m pip install --extra-index-url https://antocuni.github.io/pypy-wheels/manylinux2010 numpy
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://antocuni.github.io/pypy-wheels/manylinux2010
warning: missing-index-doctype

The package index page being used does not have a proper HTML doctype declaration.

Problematic URL: https://antocuni.github.io/pypy-wheels/manylinux2010/numpy/

note: This is an issue with the page at the URL mentioned above.
hint: You might need to reach out to the owner of that package index, to get this fixed. See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10825 for context.
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.22.2.zip (11.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  [690 lines of output]
  Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
...
  Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
  Cythonizing sources
  WARN: Could not locate executable g77
  WARN: Could not locate executable f77
  WARN: Could not locate executable ifort
  WARN: Could not locate executable ifl
  WARN: Could not locate executable f90
  WARN: Could not locate executable DF
  WARN: Could not locate executable efl
  WARN: Could not locate executable gfortran
  WARN: Could not locate executable f95
  WARN: Could not locate executable g95
  WARN: Could not locate executable efort
  WARN: Could not locate executable efc
  WARN: Could not locate executable flang
  WARN: don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
  non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
...
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\multiarray
  BUILD_ARCHITECTURE: 'AMD64', os.name='nt', sys.platform='win32'
  non-existing path in 'numpy\\core': 'build\\src.win-amd64-3.8\\numpy\\core\\src\\common'
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\common
...
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\linalg
  ### Warning:  Using unoptimized lapack ###
  ### Warning:  Using unoptimized lapack ###
  running build_py
...
  creating C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2x_oanlm\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks
  WARN: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1169] : feature 'AVX512_KNL' is disabled, MSVC compiler doesn't support it
  WARN: CCompilerOpt.__init__[1169] : feature 'AVX512_KNM' is disabled, MSVC compiler doesn't support it
  WARN: CCompilerOpt.dist_test[590] : CCompilerOpt._dist_test_spawn[714] : Flags in command (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -Inumpy\core\src\_simd -IC:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\pypy\pypy3.8-v7.3.7-win64\include -IC:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\pypy\pypy3.8-v7.3.7-win64\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt /TcC:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\test_flags.c /FoC:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2x_oanlm\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\test_flags.obj /arch:AVX512) aren't supported by the compiler, output ->
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/arch:AVX512'
  test_flags.c

  WARN: CCompilerOpt.cc_test_flags[1025] : testing failed
  WARN: CCompilerOpt.dist_test[590] : CCompilerOpt._dist_test_spawn[726] : Command (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -Inumpy\core\src\_simd -IC:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\pypy\pypy3.8-v7.3.7-win64\include -IC:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\pypy\pypy3.8-v7.3.7-win64\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt /TcC:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.c /FoC:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2x_oanlm\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.obj /arch:AVX2 /WX) failed with exit status 2 output ->
  cpu_avx512cd.c
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.c(18): error C2065: '__m512i': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.c(18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'a'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.c(18): error C2065: 'a': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.c(18): warning C4013: '_mm512_lzcnt_epi32' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.c(18): warning C4013: '_mm512_loadu_si512' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.c(18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '__m512i'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.c(18): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.c(18): error C2297: '*': illegal, right operand has type 'char *'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.c(18): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.c(19): warning C4013: '_mm512_castsi512_si128' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.c(19): error C2065: 'a': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.c(19): error C2440: 'function': cannot convert from 'int' to '__m128i'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512cd.c(19): warning C4024: '_mm_cvtsi128_si32': different types for formal and actual parameter 1

  WARN: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1490] : testing failed
  WARN: CCompilerOpt.dist_test[590] : CCompilerOpt._dist_test_spawn[726] : Command (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -Inumpy\core\src\_simd -IC:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\pypy\pypy3.8-v7.3.7-win64\include -IC:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\pypy\pypy3.8-v7.3.7-win64\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt /TcC:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.c /FoC:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2x_oanlm\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.obj /arch:AVX2 /WX) failed with exit status 2 output ->
  cpu_avx512f.c
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.c(18): error C2065: '__m512i': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.c(18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'a'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.c(18): error C2065: 'a': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.c(18): warning C4013: '_mm512_abs_epi32' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.c(18): warning C4013: '_mm512_loadu_si512' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.c(18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '__m512i'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.c(18): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.c(18): error C2297: '*': illegal, right operand has type 'char *'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.c(18): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.c(19): warning C4013: '_mm512_castsi512_si128' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.c(19): error C2065: 'a': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.c(19): error C2440: 'function': cannot convert from 'int' to '__m128i'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512f.c(19): warning C4024: '_mm_cvtsi128_si32': different types for formal and actual parameter 1

  WARN: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1490] : testing failed
  WARN: CCompilerOpt.dist_test[590] : CCompilerOpt._dist_test_spawn[726] : Command (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -Inumpy\core\src\_simd -IC:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\pypy\pypy3.8-v7.3.7-win64\include -IC:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\pypy\pypy3.8-v7.3.7-win64\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt /TcC:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c /FoC:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2x_oanlm\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.obj /arch:AVX2 /WX) failed with exit status 2 output ->
  cpu_avx512_skx.c
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(18): error C2065: '__m512i': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'aa'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(18): error C2065: 'aa': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(18): warning C4013: '_mm512_abs_epi32' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(18): warning C4013: '_mm512_loadu_si512' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '__m512i'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(18): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(18): error C2297: '*': illegal, right operand has type 'char *'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(18): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(20): warning C4013: '_mm256_abs_epi64' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(20): warning C4013: '_mm512_extracti64x4_epi64' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(20): error C2065: 'aa': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(22): error C2065: '__m512i': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(22): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'b'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(22): error C2065: 'b': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(22): warning C4013: '_mm512_broadcast_i32x8' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(24): error C2065: 'b': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(24): warning C4013: '_mm512_abs_epi16' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(25): warning C4013: '_mm512_castsi512_si128' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(25): error C2065: 'b': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(25): error C2440: 'function': cannot convert from 'int' to '__m128i'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(25): warning C4024: '_mm_cvtsi128_si32': different types for formal and actual parameter 1
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_skx.c(20): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'int' to '__m256i'

  WARN: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1490] : testing failed
  WARN: CCompilerOpt.dist_test[590] : CCompilerOpt._dist_test_spawn[726] : Command (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -Inumpy\core\src\_simd -IC:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\pypy\pypy3.8-v7.3.7-win64\include -IC:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\pypy\pypy3.8-v7.3.7-win64\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt /TcC:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c /FoC:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2x_oanlm\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.obj /arch:AVX2 /WX) failed with exit status 2 output ->
  cpu_avx512_clx.c
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(19): error C2065: '__m512i': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(19): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'a'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(19): error C2065: 'a': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(19): warning C4013: '_mm512_loadu_si512' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(19): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '__m512i'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(19): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(19): error C2297: '*': illegal, right operand has type 'char *'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(19): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(20): error C2065: 'a': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(20): warning C4013: '_mm512_dpbusd_epi32' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(20): warning C4013: '_mm512_setzero_si512' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(21): warning C4013: '_mm512_castsi512_si128' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(21): error C2065: 'a': undeclared identifier
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(21): error C2440: 'function': cannot convert from 'int' to '__m128i'
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\checks\cpu_avx512_clx.c(21): warning C4024: '_mm_cvtsi128_si32': different types for formal and actual parameter 1

  WARN: CCompilerOpt.feature_test[1490] : testing failed
  WARN: CCompilerOpt.generate_dispatch_header[2291] : dispatch header dir build\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\distutils\include does not exist, creating it
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
...
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\random\src\distributions
  running build_ext
  WARN: Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build
...
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\umath
  loops_trigonometric.dispatch.avx2.c
  numpy\core\src\npymath\npy_math_internal.h.src(897): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'unsigned short' to 'uint8_t', possible loss of data
  numpy\core\src\npymath\npy_math_internal.h.src(903): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'unsigned __int64' to 'uint8_t', possible loss of data
  numpy\core\src\umath\loops_trigonometric.dispatch.c.src(40): error C2059: syntax error: 'bad suffix on number'
  numpy\core\src\umath\loops_trigonometric.dispatch.c.src(40): warning C4305: 'function': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
...
  numpy\core\src\umath\loops_trigonometric.dispatch.c.src(109): warning C4305: 'function': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
  numpy\core\src\umath\loops_trigonometric.dispatch.c.src(110): error C2059: syntax error: 'bad suffix on number'
  Running from numpy source directory.
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2077: UserWarning:
      Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
      Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
      A better performance should be easily gained by switching
      Blas library.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2077: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2077: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
      the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
    if self._calc_info(blas):
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1902: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a470u9k7\numpy_24426d81db7f45d5a2e20cd49f3e097f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1902: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
  C:\Users\QUENTI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qem0ndd3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\include/numpy -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\distutils\include -Inumpy\core\src\common -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -Inumpy\core\src\_simd -IC:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\pypy\pypy3.8-v7.3.7-win64\include -IC:\Users\Quentin_Sarafinchan\pypy\pypy3.8-v7.3.7-win64\include -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\common -Ibuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\npymath -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt /Tcbuild\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\umath\loops_trigonometric.dispatch.avx2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\build\src.win-amd64-3.8\numpy\core\src\umath\loops_trigonometric.dispatch.avx2.obj /Zm1000 /O2 /arch:AVX2" failed with exit status 2
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
````

Answer (score 1):

Install using `conda` when you don't have clear set of dependencies available to install. Using `conda install` is a highly preferred way to install python packages.

Comment: Conda includes python, I want to use PyPy.

Answer (score 0):

The visual studio 14.0 compiler is very old, and cannot build NumPy. If you cannot update, you should use conda (as suggested by Abdullah Khilji) which will get you PyPy 3.7 if you do `conda create -n pypyenv pypy3.7`. More information at https://conda-forge.org/blog/posts/2020-03-10-pypy/